# Calling virtual methods of different derived classes in a single array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, polymorphism, components, game-engine

Ok so I am attempting to make a component/entity system for my game engine, and I have  a base `class component` which has the virtual method `update()`, and then all the different types of components are derived from that single base class. I store the pointers to these components in the an array, then loop over the array calling the update method. When I have just one type of derived class this works fine it calls the derived virtual method, but once I add a different type of derived class it starts using the base update method. Here's and example:

```
//Hold the pointers to the Components
Component** components;
```

---

```
//in the system constructor I initialize the array of components
void System::System()
{
    components = new Component*[MAX_COMPONENTS]();
}
```

---

```
//Inputlistener is a derived component   
InputListener* inputListener;
inputListener= new InputListener;

//Playercontroller is also derived component
PlayerController* playerController;
playerController = new PlayerController;

//Adds the pointer to the components array
system->add(inputListener);
system->add(playerController);
```

---

```
//loops over the array the update method is a virtual method 
system->update(); //calls the base classes update method not the derived
```

From what I have read online it seam like this should be possible since the array is just holding the pointer not the object themselves so the they should be getting sliced into the base class. If I am indeed wrong about this assumption what would be a solution?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work? On a side-note, why not use a `vector<Component*>` at the very least - preferably some smart pointer construct.

Comment: Too bad you haven't shown any code that matters. Anyway, the answer is you have a bug in some code you haven't shown.

Comment: That doesn't look wrong. Post a minimal and complete example that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Hold the pointers to the Components
std::vector<Component*> components;

//Inputlistener is a derived component   
InputListener* inputListener;
inputListener= new InputListener;

//Playercontroller is also derived component
PlayerController* playerController;
playerController = new PlayerController;

components.push_back(inputListener);
components.push_back(playerController);

for( size_t i = 0; i < components.size(); ++i ){
  Component* cmp = components.at(i);
  if( cmp ) cmp->update();
}
```

Comment: Does that actually answer any of the OP's questions (I do agree with the vector tho')

Comment: @MatsPetersson Actually I wanted to just give hint by showing some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
    public:
    virtual void update (){
        cout << "Base" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
    public:
    void update () override{
        cout << "Dervied1" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
    public:
    void update () override{
        cout << "Dervied2" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
   Base* sample[3];
   sample[0] = new Base();
   sample[1] = new Derived1();
   sample[2] = new Derived2();

   for(int i=0; i < 3; ++i){
       sample[i]->update();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I have created a link here http://codepad.org/IfnBdYIk . Can you verify your code with this and tell if you are doing anything differently ?  Because from the description of what you tried, you should not have seen the incorrect behavior, neither did I.